# Set Symfony session lifetime at login based on user attributes

Tags: symfony, security, session, lifetime

I'm working on a project where the customer wants different users to have different session lifetimes (not, mind you, cookie lifetimes).

The customer want this based on "rights" (sort of like permissions), held by each user.

For example, the default session lifetime might be 15 minutes.
Some users may have session lifetimes of one hour.
Managers sessions don't expire (lifetime = 0).

I have not been able to come up with a way to do this within the existing Symfony framework's security/session system.

I could implement something of my own and inject it somewhere in the event path, but that really seems clunky to me and like it breaks the spirit of Symfony.

Suggestions?
TIA.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a way to go with your problem.

You can implement custom session storage, here is [explanation how to do it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_configuration.html).

In details, you will implement `NativeSessionStorage` class, which comes with method `setOptions`. This method takes as param array of all php.ini values related to session configuration. If you wrap it into your business logic, it will solve your problem.